# Listening to HTML5 localStorage variable change on one page

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, dom-events, listen

I try to have a thing like in http://html5demos.com/storage-events but with the event triggering on that same page, and not on a 2nd one. (I have several webapps on 1 page)

I looked for "Listening for variable changes in JavaScript" but nothing about the localStorage variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can try see this -> http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp
and this -> http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_webstorage_local_clickcount

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to checkit out and see what I can do with it!

Answer (score 0):

My understanding was that not all browsers fire storage events on the same page, i investigated storage events as a possible part of my [store.js API](http://github.com/nbubna/store) but had to relegate event support to an extension because the implementations were so inconsistent, particularly in that area.  That extension is [here](https://raw.github.com/nbubna/store/master/src/store.bind.js), and the tests for it in my library all use iframes because of this problem.